# write command log to file in window

Tags: windows, oracle, command-line

I want to write log of following command to file in window:

```
C:\Users\The Linh>IMP system/Thelinh05@orcl FILE= D:\source\rabbit\db_dmp\billus
er.dmp FULL=Y IGNORE=Y;
```

(This command use to import data in to oracle).

I try to use this command:

```
C:\Users\The Linh>IMP system/Thelinh05@orcl FILE= D:\source\rabbit\db_dmp\billus
er.dmp FULL=Y IGNORE=Y;>log.txt
```

But it not write log to file. The output in command line is:

> Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 14 16:32:47 2016
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
>
> IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1017 encountered ORA-01017: invalid
>   username/password; logon deniedUsername:

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon at the end of your command?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution for this problem. use below command:

> IMP system/Thelinh05@orcl FILE= D:\source\rabbit\db_dmp\billuser.dmp
>   FULL=Y IGNORE=Y logfile=log.txt